# CakePHP: Filter search on one table based on values from another table

Tags: mysql, cakephp

I have a table containing user information, model name is User

```
User
----
id    full_name (for demo purposes)
1     john doe
2     jane doe
3     john smith
4     jane smith
```

The User model is linked to another model called Record

```
Record
------
userid(FK)
1
1
3
3
3
```

I also have a routine in my Controller that looks up users based on some criteria.

```
$leads = $this->User->find('list',array(
'fields' => array('User.id','User.full_name'),
'order' => array('User.full_name ASC'),
'conditions'=>array('AND'=>array(
'NOT'=>array('User.deleted_record'=>1),
 array('NOT'=>array('User.username'=>'root',
  array('User.username'=>'testuser')))
        ))
));
```

This works just fine for returning a dropdown list of users. What I need to do now is further filter the user list based on whether they have one or more records in the Record model. If they don't, they should not appear.

```
User
----
id
1
3
```

I'm guessing this will require an IN clause and a join, but I don't know the "Cake" way to set it up in my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have already set up a relationship between the user and record table in the respective models, then you should try this in the UsersController :

```
$userList = $this->User->Record->find('list', array('group' => array('Record.userid')));
```

Comment: Thanks. I was able to use the 'group'=>array('Record.userid') along with a join to get it to work. Not *completely* Cake-y, but I'm there!

Comment: Glad to be helpful :)